# Which is exactly the right GA Ecommerce Tracking Code?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, event-tracking, enhanced-ecommerce

First, I want to say, I am new in code. Recently I find the Ecommerce Tracking is not working, of course missing Ecommerce Tracking code. I search a lot from Internet, still cannot figure out, who can help me, thanks a lot.
I find the follow code:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new 
Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/gtag.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-88888888-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');

ga('require', 'ecommerce');

ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
'id': '1234', // Transaction ID. Required.
'affiliation': 'Fresh Egg', // Affiliation or store name.
'revenue': '43.66', // Grand Total.
'shipping': '3', // Shipping.
'tax': '1.29' // Tax.
});

ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
'id': '1234', // Transaction ID. Required.
'name': 'Fresh Egg', // Product name. Required.
'sku': 'AB12345', // SKU/code.
'category': 'Blue eggs', // Category or variation.
'price': '22.33', // Unit price.
'quantity': '1' // Quantity.
});

ga('ecommerce:send');

</script>
```

I donot know how to change the date, like, what "1234" means? Is this a certain date or something in from the code? And others! I know this may be a very foolish question, but I really need your help! Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is no "date" information that you need to set specifically for ecommerce. That is tracked automatically in GA. Also "1234" is the unique transaction ID or identifier for the specific transaction that has just taken place. Each of your transactions should have that, and it's something like an order ID.

Answer (score 1):

> First of all, make sure [ecommerce plugin](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce?hl=en) is enough for what you need or maybe you should use [enhanced ecommerce plugin](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce?hl=en).

You need to change, dynamically, each value depending on the transaction that is being executed.

It will depend on the programming language your site uses. For example, in php your code could be something like this:

```
   ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
    'id': '<?php echo $transacion_id; ?>', 
    'name': '<?php echo $product_name; ?>', 
    'sku': '<?php echo $sku; ?>',
    'category': '<?php echo $product_category; ?>',
    'price': '<?php echo $product_price; ?>', 
    'quantity': '<?php echo $product_quantity; ?>' 
    });
```

Consider using [Google Tag Manager to implement your Analytics Ecommerce](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZKjlIhFJMCU)

Comment: Thank you so much, you really help me a lot!